# Why can a thrown exception with hidden visibility still be caught

Tags: c++, exception, shared-libraries, visibility

I'm having a CI failure of my program which uses Boost.ProgramOptions. It fails to catch an exception thrown inside the Boost shared library. But this only happens on OSX.

The problem boils down to cross-boundary exception handling with shared objects and hidden visibility.

What happens is:

- Boost is build with hidden visibility, the exception thrown is marked with default visibility
- When consumed the exception in the Boost header is not marked with anything
- When the consuming program is build with default visibility all works as expected
- When building the consuming program with hidden visibility it fails to catch the exception on OSX only (windows and Linux work across multiple compilers)

I found:
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

> Symbol visibility is "default" by default but if the linker encounters just one definition with it hidden - just one - that typeinfo symbol becomes permanently hidden (remember the C++ standard's ODR - one definition rule).

So this (and the rest of the C++ exception paragraph) says, that the OSX behavior is what is expected.

This should also be shown by "Version 3" of http://www.ce.unipr.it/people/medici/visibility_and_shared_object.html which is basically an MWE:

my_hidden_exception.h

```
class my_exception {
  public:
  virtual ~my_exception() throw() { }
  virtual const char*
          what() const throw() { return "my_exception"; }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_hidden_exception.h"

int my_object();

int main()
{
  try{
    my_object();
  }
  catch(my_exception & e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

shared.cpp:

```
#include "my_hidden_exception.h"

int __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) my_object()
{
  throw my_exception();
}
```

Compile and run with

```
g++ -shared -o libshared.so shared.cpp -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
g++ -o main main.cpp -lshared -L. -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
./main
```

My problem now is that I'm unable to reproduce this with any GCC (7, 10) or Clang (6, 9) I tested, in all cases the exception is successfully caught which according to all sources shouldn't be possible.

Can anyone explain what I'm missing here? How can I "force" the correct behavior on Linux for better testing (OSX testers are hard(er) to come by)?

Comment: Does it fail with Clang + libc++ on Linux too? I suspect it is as I observed such a behavior in discussion for https://github.com/boostorg/function/pull/24 though  according to http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/BOOST-SYMBOL-VISIBLE-tp4673673p4673716.html it should have been the other way (`std::logic_error` is not marked as visible in libstdc++ but does in libc++). Anyway, Boost.ProgramOptions should have been fixed 6 years ago when https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/10899 was reported, try sending a PR.

Comment: On libc++ it fails too. Seems the cause is a change in libstdc++ where it compares mangled type names instead of typeinfo pointers